# fuser returns Cannot Permission denied

Tags: unix, ubuntu, docker

If I run `fuser -n tcp 80` on ubuntu 14.0.4 which is running in a docker image, I get:

```
Cannot stat file /proc/25/fd/0: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/25/fd/1: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/25/fd/2: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/25/fd/3: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/25/fd/4: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/25/fd/5: Permission denied
etc.
80/tcp:                 24
```

If I run `whoami` it returns root.

Why can I not run this command?

Answer (score 5):

That should be because of [**AppArmor**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor).

It is a  Linux Security Module implementation of name-based access controls. AppArmor confines individual programs to a set of listed files and posix 1003.1e draft capabilities.

You can see various workarounds in [issue 7276](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7276#issuecomment-153990854) or [issue 6800](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6800#issuecomment-83942232).

```
docker run -itd --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt=apparmor:unconfined mytomcat7image
```